# Web Scraping BeautifulSoup- CoinMarketCap.com historical data (find latest date)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrap the historical token data from coinmarketcap.com  and i am facing with some issues. Would like to get some help here.

For example, i want to access the all the available price data for a token

https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tether/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20180731

But the issue is how do i get the earliest start date available for each token? I found that the earliest start date is available in some javascript function instead of html tag.

A snapshot of the earliest start date in "All Time" but its a javascript function.

```
 ranges: {
        'Last 7 Days': [moment.utc().subtract(6, 'days'), moment.utc()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment.utc().subtract(30, 'days'), moment.utc()],
        'Last 3 Months': [moment.utc().subtract(3, 'months'), moment.utc()],
        'Last 12 Months': [moment.utc().subtract(12, 'months'), moment.utc()],
        'Year To Date': [moment.utc().startOf('year'), moment.utc()],
        'All Time': ["04-28-2013", moment.utc()]
```

Anyone have any idea how to go about doing this ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need use Python time and date functions to get your desired data range. Something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime


def start_of_year():
    today = datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()
    return datetime.datetime(today.year, 1, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

def get_date(d):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%m-%d-%Y')

def get_url(start, end):
    start = start.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    end = end.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    return 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tether/historical-data/?start={}&end={}'.format(start, end)


now = lambda: datetime.datetime.utcnow()
td = lambda *args, **kwargs: datetime.timedelta(*args, **kwargs)

ranges = [
    (now() - td(days=6), now()),    # last 7 days
    (now() - td(days=30), now()),   # last 30 days
    (now() - td(days=3 * 365//12), now()),   # last 3 months
    (now() - td(days=365), now()),  # last 12 months
    (start_of_year(), now()),   # year to date
    (get_date('04-28-2013'), now()) # from 04-28-2013 to now
]

for r in ranges:
    r = requests.get(get_url(*r))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    data_table = soup.select_one('table.table tbody')
    for row in data_table.select('tr'):
        print([r['data-format-value'] for r in row.select('td[data-format-value]')])
    print('-' * 80)
```

This will go through all date/time ranges and get the value data:

```
['0.999317', '1.00715', '0.993987', '0.99891', '4311410000.0', '2505427944.64']
['0.996402978897', '1.00161004066', '0.995105028152', '0.998919010162', '2404489984.0', '2498121984.0']
['0.995606005192', '1.00268995762', '0.995606005192', '0.997887015343', '2298899968.0', '2496123904.0']
['0.999553024769', '1.0043900013', '0.99117898941', '0.997117996216', '3092310016.0', '2506019840.0']
['0.996739983559', '1.00374996662', '0.99286699295', '0.997950971127', '2894500096.0', '2498967040.0']
['0.992371976376', '1.0020699501', '0.985008001328', '0.998790979385', '3514560000.0', '2488015872.0']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will take a look at it. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The website itself has defined `04-28-2013` as default the earliest date, which means they are not displaying records beyond that date.

But the lucky part is you `need not to give the exact earliest date` for getting the historical data.

For example, though the actual earliest date for DigixDAO is actually `April 18, 2016 (20160418)`, the proper results are getting displayed for default earliest date `(20130428)`.

https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/digixdao/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20180731

So the answer is do not worry about the earliest start date and just scrape.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. actually that makes sense !. Much Appreciated!